# How do I make a water effect view with openGLES on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I found this vid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVi6ThY3LRs
I wonder if that's some kind of standard effect of openGLES. I'm pretty sure it is, since I have seen this pretty often. KoiPond uses it, DuckDuckDuck uses it. A lot of games use it. They're not all astronauts. They're normal programmers ;) So how is this done? Is there any tutorial for this on the web?

Comment: how do you know they're normal programmers?

Answer (score 7):

For an old example have a look at the '[distort](http://web.archive.org/web/20120403194350/http://www.sgi.com/products/software/opengl/examples/more_samples/)' example. Note that this is a thing created back in 1992 (just looked in distort.c).

> Awesome program that causes ripples in the image wherever the mouse button is pressed. Another mode of the program acts like a sheet of rubber and can be pulled by dragging the mouse.

I managed to compile the example on my mac.

- Rename all `#include <GL/glut.h>` to `#include <GLUT/glut.h>`
- Add a `usleep(33*1000);` in the `idle()` function
- Rename the file `ripple_precalc.c` to `ripple_precalc.c.org` (or just rm it)
- Compile with "`cc *.c -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL`" will create an `a.out`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Could you see if it makes use of things that are not supported in openGLES?

Comment: I think it's basically as JeeBee describes, a mesh covered with a texture and the mesh vertices are moved with some math, I'd guess some spring dynamics. Note that you'll need to convert the code to remove glBegin()/glEnd() calls...

Answer (score 2):

(off the top of my head) Maybe a mesh distortion where the texture is pinned to the vertices and hence appears to ripple as the mesh vertices are moved? By moving a set of vertex displacements around the mesh you could make a uniform ripple like a wavefront...

Answer (score 1):

JeeBee has it right. You can base your code off this tutorial:

http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article915.asp