# Can any one suggest me a method to implement wave animation in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a water effect view with openGLES on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726738/how-do-i-make-a-water-effect-view-with-opengles-on-the-iphone)

I am developing a project in which wave animation is required.I have searched a lot in Google to get such animation but of not use.Can any one suggest me a logic to implement this animation and which framework should i use open gl or cocos 2D
thanks in advance

Comment: Got an example anywhere of what you mean by 'wave'? i.e. youtube video etc?

Comment: It's hard to imagine without screenshot. Is it from top-view or in perspective, or horizontal orthogonal view?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions in the above-linked question, you probably want to look at Apple GLCameraRipple sample code to see how to perform vertex displacement to simulate a water ripple.

Answer (score 0):

Read the "grass movement" part of [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10862/how-to-create-cool-effects-with-custom-shaders-in-opengl-es-2-0-and-cocos2d-2-x), might give you some ideas.